# How do I add an if else condition to a for loop with 2 categories in android/java

Tags: java, android, if-statement, for-loop, while-loop

This is a very generic question. I have 2 categories anews & bnews.What I plan to do is if any row in anews is selected or even if anews is selected, I want to uncheck all rows in bnews and vice versa.The code I have is doing everything except the unchecking and I am pretty much stuck on the basic construct here. what I currently have is :

```
for(CategoryCheckableRow rwa : aNews ){
    if(rwa.isSelected()){

        String catCode = rwa.getCategoryName();
        intent.putExtra("cat_name", catCode);

        break;
    }
}
```

Now what I would like to do is:

```
if(anews is selected)
{
    //uncheck every row in bnews. 

}else if (bnews is selected{
    //uncheck every row in anews
}
```

Also I am using for loop to go through every category in anews currently, I want to do the same for bnews but with the if clause such that for loop is activated for anews ONLY if bnews is not selected and vice versa. I would like to use a while loop instead of for loop.Any pointers?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can e.g. add all `anews` and `bnews` in a single collection called `news` and then loop through that `news` collection and inside that loop code your if-else block.

Comment: can you explain programmatically

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't make much sense. Programming is all about dividing and conquering. Make multiple loops for your multiple subproblems :

- one to loop through all anews and detect selection
- one to loop through all bnews and detect selection
- one to loop through all the items you want to unselect.

Comment: can you explain programmatically